# Spring annotations / ways to document spring custom events

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am working on a big spring boot application divided into different services.

As the application got larger, I started to see some deep coupling between services so I implemented a basic Pub/Sub model using Spring Events([ApplicationEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html)) on some parts of the application to decrease coupling.

Each service creates and publishes custom events, other services subscribe to the events they want to consume.

I want to document what events each service publishes and subscribes to, in order to help with readability and debugging.

Is there any specific spring annotations/ways to help with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about specific annotations but what I usually do is to have a `sealed class` to hold my events so that I can be sure that all events reside in one place:

```kotlin
sealed class MyEvent(source: Any, name: String) : ApplicationEvent(source) {

    data class SomeEvent(val source: Any, val name: String) : MyEvent(source, name)
    
    // ...
}
```

Then you can use annotations on listeners:

```kotlin
@Component
class SomeListener {

  @EventListener(condition = "#event.name eq 'hey'")
  fun handleConditionalListener(event: SomeEvent) {
    // handle event
  }
}
```

This helps with disoverability since you only need to look for `@EventListener`s.

You can also have an event listener that listens to all events and then you can draw a diagram from the information you gathered there.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we use only the javadoc to do this type of documentation. You can do like this in your service's method:

```
/**
 * @param idFilial to be fetched
 * @return Filial object in case there is a return in the search, otherwise an Optional.empty ()
 * @implNote Search for a specific Filial from an id
 * */
Optional <Filial> findById(Long idFilial);
```